# Вытащить данные если есть такой id в бд

Tags: python, mysql, telebot

Библиотека telebot на python, бд mysql

[image: Структура бд]

Вот кусок кода:

```
        if message.chat.type == 'private':
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        markup.add(item1)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'Привет '+message.from_user.first_name+ ' !\n'+
                         'Я помогаю отслеживать дни рождения в групповых чатах и '
                         'могу автоматически собирать деньги в подарок именинникам.\n\n'
                         'Добавьте меня в любую группу, используя кнопку ниже \n\n'
                         'Не беспокойтесь, мне не нужно быть администратором в группе '
                         'и я не умею читать переписку  ',reply_markup=markup)

        cursor.execute(f"select * from chats where group_id={str(message.chat.id)}")
        ll = cursor.fetchall()
        if len(ll) >= 0:
            ss = cursor.execute(f"select group_title from chats")

            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Ты пришёл из "{ss}"')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,'Я не знаю такой группы')

    else:
        markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=2)
        item2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Добавить свой ДР в каленьдарь',
                                           url=f"http://t.me/{bot.get_me().username}?start={message.chat.id}")
        markup.add(item2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, group_start_text, reply_markup=markup)
```

Юзер по кнопке из группы переходит в бота,в этой кнопке хранится id этой группы.Нужно что бы бот написал при заходе в бота из группы,из какой группы он пришел.Я пытаюсь вытащить sql запросом но не получается.Подскажите как правильно,структура бд на скрине.

[image: .]

Comment: Если я правильно понял вашу проблему - вы в sql-запросе выбираете всё строки с помощью "*"
Попробуйте так:
`cursor.execute(f"select group_title from chats where group_id={str(message.chat.id)}") `
Так же не забудьте изменить эту строку `ll = cursor.fetchall()` на: `ll = cursor.fetchone()`

Comment: File "main.py", line 58, in process_database
    if len(ll) >= 0:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: @Артем Петров, значит в этом месте у Вас в БД значение - "null", и Вы не можете проверить тип данных "None" на количество символов с помощью `len()`

Comment: нет,у меня в бд есть значение id этого чата,на скрине который прикрепил есть

Comment: попробуйте добавить где у вас проверка этот код:
`if len(ll) >= 0:
            cursor.execute(f"select group_title from chats")
            ss = cursor.fetchone()
            bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, f'Ты пришёл из "{ss}"')`

Comment: Все равно...TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()

Comment: В первоначальном коде, который вы привели - этой ошибки нет? 
И почему у Вас в БД значение "group_id" с минусом?

Comment: Да,там то же самое

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка у Вас в том, что вы путаете `chat.id` и `group_id`. То есть вы делаете следующее:

`cursor.execute(f"select * from chats where group_id={str(message.chat.id)}")
 ll = cursor.fetchall()`

Вы пытаетесь подставить в sql-запрос chat_id с пользователем.
Чтоб в этом удостовериться, напишите в коде следующее:

`print(message.chat.id)`

Вы увидите, что результат не отрицательный, и такого значения в вашей БД нет.

Так же `message.chat.id` в Телеграмме не бывают отрицательные (по крайней мере я такого не видел). Поэтому Вы получаете из этого sql-запроса тип данных - "None" и появляется ошибка TypeError из-за того, что нельзя проверить его на длину с помощью `len()`.

Чтоб Вам было проще - выводите в консоль значения, которые получаете посредством sql-запросов :)

Comment: id групп все отрицательные

Comment: Да, но то что вы передаете в sql-запрос - минус не содержит.

Comment: В качестве примера  поместите в group_id Вашего sql-запроса  - реальный id.
А так же выведите в консоль print(message.chat.id), и Вы увидите в этом разницу;)

(не уверен, что в этой библиотеке именно так, потому что работал только с pytelegrambotapi)

Comment: @АртёмПетров, я подправил уже свой ответ;)

Comment: Так а как правильно то сделать?Что бы получилось вытянуть название в сообщение

Comment: Добавил что в print(message.text)У групп отрицательный id

Comment: @АртёмПетров, к сожалению не могу проверить сейчас синтаксис `mysql`, поэтому приведу пример для Вашего случая на `sqlite`. 

    `sql = "SELECT group_title FROM chats WHERE group_id = ?" `
    `cursor.execute(sql, [(message.chat.id)])`
   `check = cursor.fetchone()`
   `print(check)`

Да, кстати, заметьте, что таких коротких идентификаторов не бывает у групп, который Вы привели в примере на фото (по крайней мере - так в pytelegrambotapi). Если Вам нужен chat_id пользователя, используйте - `message.from_user.id`